# Is there a way to use sublime text to replace Processing IDE using Python?

Tags: python, processing, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am happily using Sublime Text instead of the default Arduino IDE to work with Arduino (.ino) files, thanks to the wonderful [Stino](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino) plugin.

This plugin creates a new "Arduino" menu entry in Sublime Text, so that every command on the default Arduino IDE (and some more) is made available from inside Sublime Text, while under the hood the actual Arduino tools are called from inside the Arduino IDE application folder.

Now I am quite interested in learning the Processing toolchain so that I can make Processing + Arduino projects, and I gladly discovered that Processing now supports "Python mode", that is, goodbye Java (yay!). It even loads a lot of included examples written in Python, and everything works right out of the box.

The problem is: both Arduino and Processing default editors are unacceptably featureless, compared to Sublime Text. A lot of Arduino users with a software development background are switching to Sublime Text + Stino, and I believe it would be natural to do the same regarding Processing IDE, even more if you are now able to replace java with Python.

So my question boils down to:

> Is there any ongoing "Processing for Sublime Text" project? If not, how could I create a Build System in sublime text so that I can run Python-based Processing scripts with simple keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Basically [Processing](https://processing.org/) is based on Java and [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) is based on C.

The most common solution is using [serial communication](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing).

For Sublime you can install and use the [processing-sublime](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Processing) package ([GitHub](https://github.com/b-g/processing-sublime)) to code Processing in a more personal flexible way. For Arduino you can try that [package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Arduino-like%20IDE). If you don't like it, you can use [Arduino-Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) to compile and upload your Arduino sketches on the command line. So you can freely choose a editor.

If you don't need any Python packages (≠ programming language features like the indention), you shouldn't switch to the [Python mode](http://py.processing.org/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/jdf/processing.py)), because it's just an following extension. But that is just my opinion based on my own experience. In addition you can use it on the [command line](https://github.com/jdf/processing.py#processingpy) too.

I guess in Sublime you can create a build process, which is based on `cmd`'s. Because of that it's not an impossible task creating a new build system to compile and run all with shortcuts.